# Reading lines from file in C++

Tags: c++

Why can't I get each line in a file printed with this? It outputs nothing.

```
    string line;
    ifstream s {"book_list.txt"};
    while (getline(s, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
```

I've included fstream, sstream, string, stdio.h, stdlib.h and am using namespace std;

Comment: Check if `s.is_open()`.

Comment: Beasuse that's not even valid C++ code and won't compile. Provide a [mcve] and learn [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the file doesnt exist.
Please check with:

```
if(!s.good()) {
    // error
}
```

or

```
while (s.good()) {
    // process.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. W. this I figured out that Xcode hides it's executables and I needed to put the txt in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream s ("book_list.txt");
    if (s.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (s,line) )
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        s.close();    // Don't forget to close the file
    }
    else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

I hop it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You should do something like this:

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <fstream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {

        string sLine = "";
        ifstream infile;

        infile.open("temp.txt");

       if(infile.is_open()){

        while (getline(infile, sLine))
        {

        cout << sLine << endl;
        }
        }
        infile.close();
        cout << "Read file completed!!" << endl;

        }
```

Comment: No you shouldn't.

Comment: Why i shouldn't?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fsstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string data;
    int counter = 0;
    ifstream infile("test_file.txt");
    while (!infile.eof()){
        getline(infile , data);
        counter += 1;
    }
    cout << "The number of lines is : " << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```